# Cashing all the static assets at once in a service worker in PWA

Tags: django, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

My question is about caching all the static assets present in a seperate directory (for me it is 'static') at once in the service worker in a PWA. As we know we need to provide a path to the asset to be cashed. E.g, if we want to cache an image 'img.png' then we need to do something like this;

```
cache.add(/static/img.png)
```

where cache is the element returned by `caches.open()`.
And if we want to add multiple files we can do something like this;

```
assets = [
'static/img1.png',
'static/img2.png'
] // and so on.

cache.addAll(assets);
```

What i want to know is that if there is any way to pass directly all the files present in static folder like;

```
cache.add(/static);
```

But the above line is not working as we can only pass a valid path(URL) not a folder or just a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is 1 month when i posted this question. After doing some research(in fact a lot), I don't think there is any way of doing so. Caching assets in PWA at once is not possible and we need to provide the path(url) seprately for each and every asset and it is not affected by whether the assets are in the same dir(or some other location) or not. What matters is whether the path given is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the list of static assets programmatically and use a Django TemplateView to render the sw.js file with your list of static assets.

`sw.js` located in your Django `templates` directory

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'YourApp-1.0.0'    
const appShell = [
    {% for asset_url in static_assets %}'{{ asset_url }}',{% endfor %}
].map((partialUrl) => `${location.protocol}//${location.host}${partialUrl}`);

addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    await cache.addAll(appShell);
  })());
});
```

`views.py`

```
class ServiceWorkerView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'sw.js'
    content_type = 'application/javascript'
    name = 'sw.js'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        storage = ManifestStaticFilesStorage()
        static_assets = []
        for folder in ('css', 'icons', 'images', 'js', 'webfonts'):
            static_assets += list(get_files(storage, location=folder))
        return {
            'static_assets': static_assets
        }
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Service Worker
    path('sw.js', views.ServiceWorkerView.as_view(), name=views.ServiceWorkerView.name), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that I use to regenerate the list of static files to cache. It still needs to be started manually when static files are added or removed but it is simple and saves some time.

```
import os

#Manifest file with "%s" where should be placed the static files
serviceWorkerBase = """
var staticCacheName = "django-pwa-v" + new Date().getTime();
var filesToCache = [
    %s
];

/** THE REMAINING OF THE MANIFEST FILE SHOULD BE HERE *//

"""

#List of python app folders in which you search for static files in the "static" folder
folders = ["app1", "app2", "other folder where 'static' is present"]

filesList = []
for folder in folders:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(folder,'static')):
        for name in files:
            if name != "serviceworker.js":
                filesList.append("'"+os.path.relpath(os.path.join(path,name), folder).replace(os.sep, '/')+"'")


with open("PATH TO SERVICEWORKER.JS TO BE CREATED", "w") as f:
    f.write(serviceWorkerBase%(",\n\t".join(filesList)))
```